# LibraryLink C++ void function, mathematica wrapper

Tags: librarylink

I am trying to include a C++ function into the Mathematica wrapper. There is a void function to change the reference state.

The original wrapper includes the following C++ function.

Here is procedure to get mathematica wrapper (CoolProp.dll).

```
git clone https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp --recursive
cd CoolProp
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DCOOLPROP_MATHEMATICA_MODULE=ON -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -G 
"Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64"
cmake --build . --config Release
```

The full procedure and instruction were obtained from here.

http://www.coolprop.org/coolprop/wrappers/Mathematica/index.html#mathematica

The prerequisites are here.

http://www.coolprop.org/coolprop/wrappers/index.html#wrapper-common-prereqs

These are the codes in cpp files for a double function.
    double CoolProp::PropsSI    (   const std::string &     Output, const std::string &     Name1, double   Prop1, const std::string &  Name2, double   Prop2, const std::string &  FluidName )

The new void function I want to include is as follow.

```
void CoolProp::set_reference_stateS (   const std::string &     FluidName, const std::string &  reference_state )
```

The second function takes the first argument as fluid string and the second as the reference state string such as "ASHRAE"

I modified the Mathematica wrapper (CoolPropMathematica.cpp) in the as follows:

```
/* Include required header */
#include "CoolProp.h"
#include "HumidAirProp.h"
#include "WolframLibrary.h"

/* Return the version of Library Link */
extern "C" DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) {
return WolframLibraryVersion;
}

/* Initialize Library */
extern "C" DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData 
libData) {
return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

/* Uninitialize Library */
extern "C" DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData 
libData) {
return;
}

/* Adds one to the input, returning the result  */
extern "C" DLLEXPORT int plus_one( WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, 
MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
mreal I1;
I1 = MArgument_getReal(Args[0]);
MArgument_setReal(Res, I1+1.0);
return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}




extern "C" DLLEXPORT int PropsSI( WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, 
MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
if (Argc != 6){ return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR; }
char *outstring = MArgument_getUTF8String(Args[0]);
char *In1string = MArgument_getUTF8String(Args[1]);
mreal In1val = MArgument_getReal(Args[2]);
char *In2string = MArgument_getUTF8String(Args[3]);
mreal In2val = MArgument_getReal(Args[4]);
char *Fluidstring = MArgument_getUTF8String(Args[5]);

// PropsS version takes all strings, not single-character inputs
double val = CoolProp::PropsSI(outstring,In1string,(double)In1val,In2string,(double)In2val,Fluidstring);
MArgument_setReal(Res, val);
return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;



extern "C" DLLEXPORT int set_reference_stateS( WolframLibraryData 
libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
if (Argc != 2){ return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR; }
char *In1string = MArgument_getUTF8String(Args[0]);
char *In2string = MArgument_getUTF8String(Args[1]);
char *Fluidstring = MArgument_getUTF8String(Args[0]);
char *RefStatestring = MArgument_getUTF8String(Args[1]);    

// set_reference_stateS version takes all strings, not single-character inputs
CoolProp::set_reference_stateS(Fluidstring,RefStatestring);
// MArgument_setChar(Res, val);
return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

I used these codes in Mathematica to call the functions.

```
PropsSI = LibraryFunctionLoad["CoolProp", "PropsSI", {UTF8String, UTF8String, Real, UTF8String, Real, UTF8String}, Real]
HAPropsSI = LibraryFunctionLoad["CoolProp", "HAPropsSI", {UTF8String, UTF8String, Real, UTF8String, Real, UTF8String, Real}, Real];


setRefStateS = LibraryFunctionLoad["CoolProp", "set_reference_stateS", {UTF8String, UTF8String}, {}];
setRefStateS[{"n-Propane", "ASHRAE"}]

Print[{PropsSI["H", "T", 233.15, "Q", 0, "n-Propane"], " ASHRAE test h "}]
PropsSI["T", "P", 101325, "Q", 1, "Water"];

LibraryFunctionUnload[PropsSI];
LibraryFunctionUnload[HAPropsSI];
LibraryFunctionUnload[setRefStateS];
```

These are the outputs from the program.

I managed to general the .dll file, but that particular function doesn't work since it seems the function is not loaded.

[image: LibraryFunctionLoad output]

My question is: "Is the codes added to load (set_reference_stateS) function correct?".

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please give some context, link to the relevant libraries (CoolProp??) and state the question explicitly.  "Doesn't work" is not a question.  Also, it was not stated *what* does not work, how it fails, what errors you see, how you compiled and loaded the library, what command you ran when it failed, etc. etc

Comment: I have modified the post including all the necessary links and information as suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem.

The correct codes in .cpp file for mathematica wrapper are as follow.

```
extern "C" DLLEXPORT int set_reference_stateS( WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
if (Argc != 2){ return LIBRARY_FUNCTION_ERROR; }
char *Fluidstring = MArgument_getUTF8String(Args[0]);
char *RefStatestring = MArgument_getUTF8String(Args[1]);    

// set_reference_stateS version takes all strings, not single-character inputs
CoolProp::set_reference_stateS(Fluidstring,RefStatestring);
// MArgument_setChar(Res, val);
return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
```

In Mathematica, we have to call like this:

```
setRefStateS = LibraryFunctionLoad["CoolProp",
```

"set_reference_stateS", {UTF8String, UTF8String}, "Void"];

```
setRefStateS["n-Propane", "ASHRAE"]

Print[{TestPropsSI["H", "T", 233.15, "Q", 0, "n-Propane"], " ASHRAE test h "}]

setRefStateS["n-Propane", "DEF"]

Print[{TestPropsSI["H", "T", 233.15, "Q", 0, "n-Propane"], " DEF test h "}]
```

The output is now: 
(* {-4.88073*10^-12, ASHRAE test h } *)
(* {105123., DEF test h } *)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In what you show, the problem is a syntax error in `LibraryFunctionLoad`.  The last argument (the return type) cannot be `{}`.  It must be `"Void"` for a function that does not return anything.

---

However, I see some other issues in the code. When a string is passed to a LibraryFunction, it must be manually freed after use.  See [`UTF8String_disown`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/ref/callback/UTF8String_disown.html).

As it stands, the function has a memory leak because it does not free the input strings.

Comment: Thank you. I have included codes to free the memory.